# Wrong display of a question's "last active" property

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timestamps

The relative date shown to the right of a question seems to be incorrect.

Due to an emergency, I had to come in to work today (a Sunday) and one of my last opened tabs was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29302551/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-session-register).

[image: Screenshot]

Note, how it says "active: yesterday". The pop-up shows "2015-03-27 14:06:49Z" which is definitely not yesterday, but the day before. The same is true for the comments to the question and its answer.

**Update**

The pop-up text comes from the `<span>` element's `title` tag which is periodically used to update the contents via Javascript. It should be trivial to determine *when* yesterday was since the script has both a UTC stamp (from the title) and the client's date and timezone for comparison.

<sub>* Before taking the screenshot and posting this question I took care of that emergency first.</sub>

Comment: "yesterday" means between 24 and 48 hours ago; that'll be "2 days ago" in about 2 hours 7 minutes.

Comment: @Ben, For me, that word doesn't mean 'between 24 and 48 hours ago', it means, well, yesterday ! If it's Sunday, I expect 'yesterday' to mean Saturday, and not 'between 24 and 48 hours ago'.   Should be fixed IMHO.

Comment: Yes, but "yesterday" is relative depending on where in the world you live @JonasCz. For me, "yesterday" is 12 hours 15 minutes ago, if I were in Australia at the moment it's 22 hours 15 minutes ago.

Comment: @Ben First off, I agree with JonasCz: *yesterday* is the day before today and not a time in an obscure range of hours. Secondly, those `<span>` elements are updated via Javascript which is a clientside thing; with the UTC stamp in its title, it's trivial to determine *when* yesterdays was. Irrelevant of which timezone you're in.

Comment: @Ben: To emphasize Linus's point, yesterday should simply be measured in UTC, like *every single other date-related aspect of SE*. Problem solved, no further issues, case closed.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. It is *yesterday* for someone somewhere in the world still. Relative dates take this into account. Up to 24 hours ago is *today*, up to 48 hours ago is *yesterday*. In other words, relative times use [Anywhere on Earth calendar designations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth).

You can always hover over a relative date to see the absolute timestamp, in ISO 8601 format. Times are always in the UTC timezone.

Comment: It's a shame HTML doesn't have a `<time>`-element for displaying a UTC time (optionally only chosen parts) in the local time-zone.

Comment: This Answer is an explanation for this issue and why it occurs but the bug still exists. And having such a thing in this perfect platform is not acceptable.

Comment: @Mehrdad: It's not a bug. It works that way by design.

Comment: I got you. I want to see the correct date. How should I register the request for changing this design? @Cerbrus

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry that you find it unacceptable. Note however that *I am a volunteer on this platform*, not a developer, so telling me that you find this unacceptable is not going to have much effect.

Comment: @Mehrdad: personally, I think the developers have more urgent matters to address, _and_ I find the design acceptable, once I understood the reasoning. It could well be that others agree with me on that. However, if you want to see it changed and you've confirmed that there isn't already a feature request posted for this, you are free to post a new question with the [tag:feature-request] tag. Do read the [FAQ for proposing changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over) first.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for the accurate explanation and guide. I agree with you that there are more urgent matters to address, I just want to register this one as a known issue for the feature.