# Dynamic Favicon to show if you have an inbox alert

Tags: feature-request, favicon

Suggestion: A Dynamic Favicon

Overview: The general idea of having a dynamic favicon would be the ability to alter its image dependent on several circumstances. These circumstances would aid user experience although just a little thing it is extremely helpful.

Circumstances for use: I can think of 5 circumstances (both pretty similar) where this could be used and in my opinion I personally would find beneficial.

1. **Addition of a red dot -** My first circumstance would be when you receive a response to a question. Quite often I find myself checking over to the tab looking to see if a helpful member of the community has given me a response and in some cases it takes multiple clicking forward and backwards until I get that response.

I believe changing the favicon to have a red dot when an answer is submitted to a your question would be a small tweak that's very beneficial. Not having to check the tab every other minute would not only be more efficient for the user but also saves time in general.

2. **Addition of a blue dot** - This blue dot would be triggered upon a comment being added to your question/answer again for the same reasons listed for point 1.
3. **Addition of a yellow dot** - This yellow dot would be triggered upon a comment/answer on a favourited question not necessarily your own. This again is just a nice helpful indication to check the tab instead of checking constantly.
4. **Addition of an orange dot** - This orange dot would be triggered upon an edit of comment/answer on your post.
5. **Addition of a purple dot** - This purple dot would trigger upon an upvote/downvote on your comment/question/answer/reputation gain.

**Raised Points of Arguments**

1. Using the favicon to display reviews would mean a constant dot taking away from the value of a dynamic favicon.

Response: I 100% agree, I think it's important that the change has value and more times than not the favicon remains the regular favicon. Deciding on which actions trigger the change in favicon is a great discussion point and one that would have to be considered in order to not take away value from this feature.

2. For regular users of the site, there would be a dot at all times deeming this not helpful.

Response: Again another excellent point, perhaps having the ability to toggle if you would like to receive the dynamic favicon in certain circumstances would be beneficial for these users. As they may want to be notified of some of these alerts but not all. Thanks for the contribution!

**Other Approaches to Notifying the User Worth Discussing**

@Stephen Leppik - Due to the limitation of the favicon in most browsers, perhaps the alteration to the tab title to change to a (1) or however many notifications you have. *Response: Would 100% agree if this limitation takes away from favicon feature.*

Comment: Are the downvotes people voting if this should/should not be a feature or due to the structure of my suggestion. If the latter please explain how I can improve it for future posts. Much appreciated!

Comment: For feature requests, it's generally the former.  You haven't really provided any value for this change, so many people won't agree with it.

Comment: @fbueckert no problem thanks for clarifying :) I will edit the suggestion to perhaps add some more value!

Comment: [See this post for some tips on writing feature requests.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over)

Comment: My fear is they'd use it to indicate that there are review actions available... and thus always have a dot...

Comment: @KevinB great point! I think it's important that limiting the use of a dynamic favicon is important so that the majority of time it is not set to a dot of some variety but in fact the regular icon. Completely agree with your point!

Comment: For high frequency contributors, there would be a constant dot regardless, just because of how much they use the site, or how often they get notifications. For them, there would be zero point in this, and it could be actively annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most browsers, favicons, like most images, are cached. They're only refreshed if the user uses a full refresh (Cmd+F5), they're never updated individually, and Safari only shows them in bookmarks, which mostly defeats the idea of using it to draw attention to the tab. So allow me to make a counter-proposal: you know this thing from the main page and question lists?

> (1) Meta Stack Overflow

The (1) is added through when a new question would appear at the top of the list. How about we add inbox events (the red number in the header) to it on the homepage? Or even, new edits, comments, or answers in question pages.

Comment: I could also get behind an alteration to the tab title, I would deem any additional notification to say an action has occurred would be beneficial!