# A global shortcut for the search box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to have a shortcut for the search box like Wikipedia, for example <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Hello Polluks, please follow the [tag guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) when creating a feature request, specifically the paragraph "Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature." Your question doesn't currently contain any sort of justification as to why this feature is needed and why it's worth the development time to implement.

Comment: Also consider reading [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/7795130) which gives some more suggestions and input on how to make a good feature request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We already support keyboard shortcuts. Just enable them in your [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), then press <kbd>S</kbd> to jump to the search box.

For more information on this feature, see the [`keyboard-shortcuts` tag wiki page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/keyboard-shortcuts/info).