# Cannot find question in duplicate list

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861988/how-to-fill-a-certain-area-with-color-in-canvas-not-stroke-filling-not-drawin) is duplicate of *[How do I do flood fill on the HTML canvas in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077955/how-do-i-do-flood-fill-on-the-html-canvas-in-javascript)*, but when I try to set duplicate flag and type it - the question is not found:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to enter the link there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I try to enter link too - not works

Comment: Great dupe by the way. The duplicate search really needs improvement ... And yes, I were only able to close it after upvoting the answer on the other question (which deserves more than one upvote though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dupe targets need to have a positively scored answer (or belong to the same asker than the question to be closed). Since that question had no upvoted answers, it was not elegible to be a dupe target and the dupe-search wouldn't offer it as a result no matter how you searched for it.

Since this was posted the answer in the dupe received an upvote, and a gold-badge in JS dupe-hammered the question you were trying to close.

This is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Maybe it should be better documented somewhere, but that would be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: May be system in this case should show message like: `this question exists but cannot be set as duplicate because...`

Comment: Maybe. With further refining, maybe that could be a different question stated as feature-request.

Comment: I change question tag from bug to feature-request

Comment: Changing the tag is not enough. Post a new question and explain your feature-request. Better read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375365/how-do-i-present-a-proposal-for-change-or-write-a-feature-request-for-stack-over) first, which would help you to better prepare your FR.

Comment: How about showing non viable dupetargets ina greyed-out way?

Comment: @JonasWilms [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384264/860099)

Comment: The duplicate search never returns unanswered questions, not even when they’re valid targets. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284733/323179). At some point I stopped using it to find things (but also because it doesn’t search answers).