# Add info about why existing question cannot be found in duplicate list

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, user-interface

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861988/how-to-fill-a-certain-area-with-color-in-canvas-not-stroke-filling-not-drawin) is duplicate of this: [How do i do flood fill on HTML canvas in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077955/how-do-i-do-flood-fill-on-html-canvas-in-javascript) but when I try to set duplicate flag and type it (or copy **URL**) - the question is not found:

[image]

It will be good if system give information about why existing questions cannot be found in duplicate list e.g:

> Question exists but cannot be chosen as duplicate. Dupe targets need to have a positively scored answer (or belong to the same asker than the question to be closed). Since that question had no upvoted answers, it was not eligible to be a dupe target and the dupe-search wouldn't offer it as a result no matter how you searched for it.

More - [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/384263/860099)

Comment: If you know the question is already present you have probably seen it. At the same time you could have checked if it was eligible as a dupe target and saved yourself the effort of inserting the title there.

Comment: Internal search based on exact title has been broken since the site began. Google exists for a reason ...

Comment: @Lundin As a user, I wouldn't think that copying the URL would allow me to enter the question if the search has told me it wouldn't. That would be a very confusing bit of UX.

Comment: This falls into the UX bugs and feature requests. Stack Overflow has a very poor track record of fixing them. You are wishing for a Unicorn. Consider, this issue has already been reported and nothing has been done.

Comment: **Please**, for the love of all that is holy, do **not** use a dupe target that is itself a dupe!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'd suggest just changing the existing search message to:

> Your search returned no questions with upvoted or accepted answers

This applies whether or not more information about the criteria used is provided somewhere.

This would be more in line with the message you get when you provide a URL:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

I think for every possible question there are a few similar questions, but most of them do not have a good answer, therefore the current way to show only possible dupetargets is good, however there are cases like this were it would be great to extend the search.

I'd propose the following:

A new button gets added under the questions, named "Show non-dupetargets", that queries for all questions filtering out all possible dupetargets, so that only questions are shown that did not appear in the list already. These questions then get added below the other questions.

Comment: Yes please, I do propose it to be a checkbox rather than a button though ;) The list itself will already say exactly what any text blurb can say as you will see a downvoted status, a closed status or a lack of answers.

Comment: @gimby but then the opposite question might come up: "Why can't I dupevote for it even though it is shown in the list?" By adding a button that has to be clicked explicitly, this is always clear.

Comment: I don't see how that differs from a checkbox which needs to be clicked explicitly.

Comment: I prefer instead show everything, and when trying to close then show a JIT message indicating the reason why it coudln't be closed.