# Is searching by user not working?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search

If I enter the following criteria in the search bar:

```
user:forestg
```

The search results list is the following, very highly-voted questions of all times, instead of questions by the (my)user:

> [image: search-result]

No matter what username I enter, the results are the same.

Is there something I do wrong? The helper suggests this is the right format:

> `user:1234` search by author

Comment: Not a bug. You need to search by user id (integer), not username. In your case `user:3486691`

Comment: [179 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3486691)

Comment: The user experience could be improved by automatically showing, when used improperly, a hint similar to @yivi's comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `1234` in that helper is the user *ID*, not the user*name*. In your case it's 3486691, so [searching for `user:3486691`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3486691) works, but it's even easier to use the special [`user:me`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame) operator which automatically inserts your own user ID. This option is mentioned in the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) under 'User Operators'.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way, to search by username though?

Comment: No, not via the standard search function. You'd have to find the user ID first. Searching for all posts by users whose name starts with 'Forest' would require a [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) query.

Comment: Remember that user names are not required to be unique, @ForestG. That's why it doesn't make sense to search by user name. But I agree with Stephane in a comment above: it would definitely improve the UI to at least give a warning about this, if not a user-picker-thingadongdong.

Comment: Indeed. Although I disagree with you on the statement, that it does not make sense to search by username, if that is not unique. This might make the result list more noisy, but nevertheless a useful feature, as most of the time, people remember usernames instead of ID-s. If I want to search for a specific user's questions, I will do it from their profile page, not by extracting their user id and entering it to the search. There should be a search for profiles feature I guess. (the specific case was that I wanted to find a co-worker by his username)

Answer (score 4):

While this has been resolved, I do think allowing a search term like `usernm:hello1234` would be nice. Even though usernames do not have to be unique, it could just show all posts made by users with that exact name.

Comment: If you'd like to see a new feature, please ask a new question with the tag [meta-tag:feature-request]. Please read the [FAQ page about feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/215552) before writing it though.