# Is there a way to get a notification on questions you did not ask?

Tags: support, notifications, bookmarks

Is there a way to subscribe to a specific question and be notified when new answers/comment to that question has been posted? Similar to the case if you were the owner of that question.

P.S: Clicking the star next to the upvote/downvote button doesn't do the job I am describing.

Comment: @ErikA, the question is asking the same thing as I am asking, however, the answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes, I know. Usually I'd suggest you'd start a bounty to draw additional attention to it. If you want to push this as a new feature request, even though it's been asked before, please consider following [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/7296893)

Comment: Thank you, I have already marked the question as it was asked before.