# Constant points reduction

Tags: support, deleted-questions

- Points in my profile have been constantly reducing.
- I am sure certain questions are getting deleted that have my accepted answers. (This is, of course, not from "User was removed".)
- Can Stack Exchange developers/moderators give us a log of all the questions that are getting deleted
  and the reason behind them?

The current action of deletion looks completely anonymous.

Also, can we have a system of reversal
of sequential flags for deletion from the same user, like we have reversal of sequential
upvotes or downvotes from the same user?

**P.S:** Do let me know if those logs exist somewhere, just in case if I have overlooked something.

Comment: Does your answers page have the option to view deleted recent answers?

Comment: The mods can for sure not give you the reason for deletion. How would they know why a user voted to delete? About the automatic flag: Not sure if this is possible since they are probably not voting to delete your answer but a question where you have an answer to.

Comment: @BoltClock How do I view it? Is there any defined permalink ?

Comment: @BDL Asking them just incase, because when they review flags, there must be some reason associated with it. I believe the system should be giving access to previously reviewed flags.

Comment: *"The current action of deletion looks completely anonymous"* - not exactly. If it was deleted by votes you have a banner with the voters - just like closing. If it was deleted by the Roomba you'll see it was deleted by the community mod. Of course someone could "rig" the Roomba by voting to make a post eligible for deletion which is indeed anonymous...

Comment: Regular users can vote to delete. Since you have more than 10k, you have this privilege as well for closed questions older than 3 days.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I meant from my perspective since I had  my answer accepted.

Comment: @nice_dev: Only the closing system requires you to choose a reason. Deleting is like flagging. You click on it and it's done, no reason to enter. Also note, that a single user wouldn't be able to delete stuff, there are always multiple users required.

Comment: @yivi Yes I do realize that.

Comment: Then why do you mention flags and flag reasons?

Comment: @nice_dev: No permalink for that. I can show you your deleted answers, which includes the names of those who voted to delete the questions you answered since you have 10k rep, but you must promise not to go after them.

Comment: @nice_dev I don't see how acceptance plays a role. Either the question with your answer was deleted in that case the banner is at the top of the page, or your specific answer was deleted in that case the banner is on the answer itself...

Comment: @BDL So you mean the questions to whom I answered are all deleting their questions? Either via flagging or self deletion, I presume there should be a log in that points icon of what exactly happened.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: Answer accepts are +15 - you lose this when the question gets deleted by vote. There were no upvotes on the answers in question - only accept votes.

Comment: @yivi Because some user/users are doing that, and question deletions are reflecting in my rep.

Comment: But they are not using flags. They are most likely using delete votes.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok I won't go after them. Just need the clarity, which should by the way be available for every user with required rep.

Comment: @yivi maybe I confused terms. Yes, the votes or flags or whatever the means available for users with higher rep

Comment: But votes, as explained earlier, do not require choosing "a reason", and they are not mod reviewed, just FYI.

Comment: @yivi Ok, I am unable to see a vote for deletion option. Maybe my rep is less. But, in general, votes for deletion should be accompanied with reason, like we have for close votes.  I am not sure if this system is yet to be implemented for deletions.

Comment: Since you have more than 10k, you have access to the vote-to-delete privilege: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools. And again, close votes are the exception in requiring a reason, all the other types of votes do not require picking a reason or posting a comment. The system is not "yet to be implemented", it's simply not designed that way and (as far as I know), not planned to change.

Comment: @yivi Ok, fair enough.

Comment: **Just a side question:** Why does someone clarifying things have to be accompanied with downvotes?

Comment: There's a [recently deleted questions](//stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/4964822) link at the bottom of your [questions list](//stackoverflow.com/users/4964822/nice-dev?tab=questions) and a [recently deleted answers](//stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/4964822) link at the bottom of your [answers list](//stackoverflow.com/users/4964822/nice-dev?tab=answers). Your [reputation page](//stackoverflow.com/users/4964822/nice-dev?tab=reputation) should also explicitly tell you what your changes in reputation are and the posts which are associated with the change.

Comment: @Makyen: Oh, so there *are* permalinks...

Comment: @Makyen Thanks a lot for the links. Will refer them next time for more clarity.

Comment: *Why does someone clarifying things have to be accompanied with downvotes?* If that is about your meta question then I have to say it reads more like a conspiracy theory then an honest attempt learning what might have caused the issue you're facing.

Comment: "I demand transparency" does not come across as a request for clarification. Although I guess literally it is.

Comment: @rene What sounded like _conspiracy theory_ ?

Comment: @khelwood That was actually an additional note with respect to the above points in the question.

Comment: How about: *I believe this is happening because someone has been witch hunting my profile for personal reasons*? That doesn't read as if you consider that you might have a stake in the issue. Instead we need to find a witch we can blame, preferable with their name, email, phonenumber, homeaddress so we can pay them a house visit.

Comment: @rene I said _I believe_ this is happening, I didn't claim _I assure_.  The reason being, in the recent times, some users keep pointing out optimizations in my answer which I always welcome but more optimization could to less readability for OP who has asked the question. In retrospect, I believe some user might have started this flagging stuff. Also, I never said we need to find the witch. My question overall was just to have more clarity on finding out logs and if we can push reversal of sequential delete votes from the same user.

Comment: You asked why you got down votes, I explained it for you.  That is all I can do.

Comment: @rene. Removed it. Could you remove your downvote(if you did)? In fact, this is a request to all who did it as the question looks more filtered now.

Comment: My downvote stays. I don't think this type of questions are useful, no matter how they are worded.

Comment: Please take into account you tagged your question "feature-request". Not only downvotes can be used to express disagreement with the proposal on FRs, but for a proposal this seems poorly researched and not clearly explained. If you ever want to propose another change, reading [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375365/1426539) before doing so might be helpful.

Comment: @yivi that is nice, I stopped reading before I reached the "feature request". So even if worded neutrally the FR would still be down vote worthy from my perspective. It is better to separate those anyway (one question per question) to prevent having no idea what the votes are for or being able to properly address issues in all parts of a multipart question.

Comment: @rene Few minutes back your reason was conspiracy theory and now it is for _I don't think this type of questions are useful, no matter how they are worded_

Comment: @yivi I tried to remove the FR tag but now I see [this](https://imgur.com/a/0zn0bZO)

Comment: I like to cover many bases. And I do some mind reading of the other voters. Between myself and yivi we get pretty good at this.

Comment: You need to add back the support tag, remove the feature-request tag AND the feature request text from the question. If that is what you want to achieve: a plain support request to help you understand some mechanics of the site and its community.

Comment: @rene Kudos for such a quality. But next time, please take your reason also into account if you are justifying reasons for downvotes. This is because the person on the other side doesn't understand if you are saying in general or adding your perception into account too.

Comment: @rene Restored the support tag. I had added that initially but  Tomerikoo removed it in between.

Comment: We're getting there. Are you going to remove *Also, can we have a system of reversal of sequential flags for deletion from the same user, like we have reversal of sequential upvotes or downvotes from the same user?* or do you insist on keeping that in your question?

Comment: @rene I can remove it but the last line in the accepted answer has a line on it. So, I am unsure if future readers find the question inconsistent with the answer.

Comment: fair enough, we'll leave it at this then

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As a 10k user you can view your deleted answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a4964822%20is%3aanswer%20deleted%3a1). I sorted by newest so the answers you're referring to are there. As mentioned, the names of those who voted to delete (or undelete, close, reopen) a question are shown to you, strictly for your information as a 10k user with responsibilities only and not for you to act against them. So the transparency is definitely there.

I can't tell you why the questions you answered were deleted, but it's highly unlikely anybody is deleting questions *because you answered them*. I'm sure they're clearing away many questions of this nature on a daily basis. I can't offer much advice for you other than avoid questions that are frequent duplicates, downvoted, and/or will eventually get deleted by vote. Sometimes these questions aren't immediately obvious, for example the questions I looked at aren't blatantly low quality or off-topic, but presumably they've been asked so many times that there really isn't any need for more of them, and that's probably why they're getting deleted (I haven't answered a PHP/MySQL question in yonks, but I know exactly how it feels). So in general you may need to exercise more discretion with the questions you answer. That way you're less likely to lose upvote and accept reputation to questions getting deleted.

As for reversal of delete votes, there have been a few discussions going on very recently about delete wars, deletions by a small group of users, etc, that may be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, I would keep your advise in mind next time when answering questions.  Not that I spend time on SO just for rep, but it was like a disrespect for the hardwork, but I get what you mean. So, will be careful next time.

Comment: You might want to consider using the following link: [link for any >10k SO user to search for their own deleted, public SO posts (i.e. not Teams posts), sorted by newest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3Ame+deleted%3Ayes&searchOn=1)

Comment: @Makyen The link in the answer is more targeted as I wanted it for the answers I gave.

Comment: @nice_dev The primary thing I was trying to convey was the answer would be more generally applicable if it used a link that worked for anyone who has > 10k to find their own posts by using `user:me`, rather than a hard coded user ID number. The link in the answer works *only* for you & moderators, because non-moderators can't only search for their own deleted posts. Using `user:me` makes the link work for any >10k user. You likely experience very little difference between the two links, other than one is all posts and the other is answers, which is adding `is:answer` to the search criteria.

Comment: @Makyen Fair enough. Yes, your link is more in general.

Comment: @Makyen just FYI, the link in the answer works for everyone over 10k, exactly as if it said `user:me`. When searching for `deleted:1`, the `user` part seems to be ignored unless you have mighty mod powers.

Comment: @yivi Interesting. Thanks for telling me. I *thought* I'd tried such a search prior to being a moderator and had it not worked at all.