# Put the last edit message at the right of "Asked: Viewed: Views:", on the top, to avoid three operations to discover this change and its purpose

Tags: feature-request, edits

I have edited a question today and also added an edit message to it.

> Adding information : I'm running Kafka and its Java extractor program locally. 3.1.0, 2.8.1 Kafka versions tested. I believe in a configuration problem.

When I return to my question, in normal user view, I can see "*edited xxx mins ago*" at the bottom of my question, but not why. Of course, I can click on its link to learn more.

But instead of having:

1. to go to the bottom of a question to see if a question experienced a change since your last visit
2. then clicking on the link to discover what was the purpose of that change,
3. then clicking on the link to return back to the question,

What about displaying its last edit message in the top of the post?

[image]

Comment: Why? The vast majority really don't care what the last edit message was, indeed you might be the only one.

Comment: @Nick do you have a source for that statement? A survey?

Comment: @Marc My only source is the fact that I don't believe this to be a duplicate request, and the fact I can't for the life of me understand why this would be useful. I mostly needed padding for the _"Why?"_ - You've not given any indication as to why this would be useful. As per [How do I present a proposal for change or write a feature request for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375366/3270037) (linked to in the [meta-tag:feature-request] tag wiki): *"Clearly explain and justify your suggestion ... Why will it benefit the site?"*

Comment: @MarcLeBihan "*you have a source for that statement?*" I'd like to see what data points you used when making this feature request that shows that the edit reason needs higher visibility.

Comment: Note: the edit message is not *accurate*, user can write what ever they wants, I believe it is not even mandatory. It is eventually (slightly) helpful for reviewers, but not for the *usual* user that is just seeking some answers.

Comment: Why do you feel this is important? Knowing what changed is only relevant for the people familiar with the previous iteration; I would guess those aren't many. When I personally need to check changes for posts I follow, the actual diff is much more helpful than an – often meaningless – edit message.

Comment: @user16320675 it's not mandatory for those who can edit directly (OP and 2k-er). For suggested edit, it's mandatory though. But it's true that users can write anything, like [this user's habit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random?tab=activity&sort=revisions).

Answer (score 19):

Does not seem like a useful feature to have.

Many if not most edit messages are something like *"added 85 characters in body"*, or *"edited tags"*, which is hardly exciting stuff to put on the post.

Edit messages *can* be useful for other editors and or reviewers, but not for the primary consumers of a post.

If one needs to mention something of substance that other readers might find useful when reading a post, the edit message is **not** the place to put it. The edit itself is.